# Changes on the view is not reflected in ng-click's event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

So I have this HTML:

```
<body ng-app="calculator" ng-controller="calculatorCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="num1" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="num2" />
      <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
      <label>{{result}}</label>
</body>
```

and this JS:

```
angular.module('calculator', [])

.controller('calculatorCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.num1 = 0;
    $scope.num2 = 0;
    $scope.result = 0;
    $scope.add = function(){
        console.log($scope.num1);
        console.log($scope.num2);
        $scope.result = parseInt($scope.num1) + parseInt($scope.num2);
        console.log($scope.result);
    };
});
```

In my controller, I have 3 variables, `num1`, `num2`, and `result`. Plus, I have a function named `add`. The function should change `result` value into `num1+num2`.

I bind the function to button click event by using `ng-click` property.
I also bind `num1`, `num2`, and `result` to their respective components.

However, I find that `num1` and `num2`'s values are always zero. Below is the the result of console.log:

```
0
0
0
```

I know I can change the HTML into this:

```
<body ng-app="calculator" ng-controller="calculatorCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="num1" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="num2" />
      <label>{{parseInt(num1)+parseInt(num2)}}</label>
</body>
```

And it is going to work perfectly.

But I'm still confused, why is the first approach doesn't work?

**EDIT:** This seems to have something to do with ionic framework. I deleted the irrelevant codes in order to let everyone focus on where I thought the problem is. Apparently I was wrong. So here again the working code and the not working code:

**This doesn't work:**

```
angular.module('calculator', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('calculatorCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.num1 = 0;
    $scope.num2 = 0;
    $scope.result = 0;
    $scope.add = function(){
        console.log($scope.num1);
        console.log($scope.num2);
        $scope.result = parseInt($scope.num1) + parseInt($scope.num2);
        console.log($scope.result);
    };
});
```

**This works:**

```
angular.module('calculator', [])
.controller('calculatorCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.num1 = 0;
    $scope.num2 = 0;
    $scope.result = 0;
    $scope.add = function(){
        console.log($scope.num1);
        console.log($scope.num2);
        $scope.result = parseInt($scope.num1) + parseInt($scope.num2);
        console.log($scope.result);
    };
});
```

The question is now: What's wrong with ionic?

**UPDATE AGAIN:**

I don't know exactly, but seems that it will works if I put the variables as object property. This works perfectly with ionic:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="calculator" ng-controller="calculatorCtrl">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Calculator</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" ng-model="data.num1" />
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" ng-model="data.num2" />
          </label>
          <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="add();">Add</button>
          <label>{{data.result}}</label>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('calculator', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

            // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
            // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
            // a much nicer keyboard experience.
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})

.controller('calculatorCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.data = {
        num1 : 0,
        num2 : 0,
        result : 0,
    }
    $scope.add = function(){
        $scope.data.result = parseInt($scope.data.num1) + parseInt($scope.data.num2);
    }
});
```

**New Question:**

Why this one works, while the old one doesn't?

Comment: works for me, see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HCUn9EmkqdsAa5kSvRoi)

Comment: Well, seems the problem is laid in ionic framework. Not quiet sure why.